# What does the phrase "plot your route" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "plot your route" in the following sentence (not available online):

*In the game, you’ll ***plot your route*** by the stars, tapping to thrust towards the nearest one. When you arrive, you’ll circle it automatically.*

The text is from the description of the game "Little White Rocket". Here is a description of the game from a different source:

*Little White Rocket is an inexpensive tappable toy, where each touch launches your craft along a path of stars, some of which aren't visible until you get close or complete a particular orbit.*

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

To *plot a route* on a map is, in its most literal sense, to draw a line on it indicating the path you intend to travel; *plot* here is a verb in the same sense as plotting a graph.  The phrase is also used metaphorically when nobody is actually drawing a line, or indeed has an actual map to draw on, but is deciding upon the course a planned journey of any sort, whether a literal geographical one or not (e.g. *"the CEO plotted a course for the company through the economic turmoil"*).

Comment: Although the phrase most commonly refers to planning an intended route in advance, I believe it can also mean recording the route on a map as you travel it, and this may have been the more common meaning in the days of sailing ships.